# Why is Azure Front Door breaking content-type headers that are set in a HttpHandler?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, httphandler, azure-front-door

We are running an ASP.NET MVC 5 app on .NET 4.8 in Azure. I setup a `HttpHandler` to add a header to static files. It works without issue on our app service that does not have Front Door, but on the one that does, it seems the `Content-Type` header is getting lost on some of the files inconsistently.

The only thing consistent is if the `HttpHandler` is hit, the problem arises (I can set my variable `ConfigHelper.IsUsingAccessControlAllowOrigin` to false to skip the addition of the header and it still occurs).

Static files are not getting loaded due to this error:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/Scripts/select2.full.js' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Here is the `HttpHandler` code:

```
public class CorsHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    protected RequestContext RequestContext { get; set; }

    public CorsHttpHandler() : base() { }

    public CorsHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        this.RequestContext = requestContext;
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (ConfigHelper.IsUsingAccessControlAllowOrigin && !context.Response.Headers.AllKeys.Any(x => x.Equals(ConfigHelper.AccessControlAllowOriginKey, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
            context.Response.AddHeader(ConfigHelper.AccessControlAllowOriginKey, ConfigHelper.WildCardAsterik);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

I configured the `HttpHandler` like this in the `web.config` (side-bar: I set them this way because the comma delimited path would not work):

```
<add name="CorsHttpHandlerCss" 
     verb="*" path="*.css" 
     type="Example.Mvc.Handlers.CorsHttpHandler, Example.Mvc" 
     preCondition="managedHandler" />
<add name="CorsHttpHandlerJs" 
     verb="*" path="*.js" 
     type="Example.Mvc.Handlers.CorsHttpHandler, Example.Mvc" 
     preCondition="managedHandler" />
<add name="CorsHttpHandlerJpg" 
     verb="*" path="*.jpg" 
     type="Example.Mvc.Handlers.CorsHttpHandler, Example.Mvc" 
     preCondition="managedHandler" />
<add name="CorsHttpHandlerPng" 
     verb="*" path="*.png" 
     type="Example.Mvc.Handlers.CorsHttpHandler, Example.Mvc" 
     preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

One option to resolve this is to abandon the setting of this header in C#, buy the Premium instance of Front Door / CDN and then set the header there.  However, I think this needs to be solved because how are people using `HttpHandler`s with a Front Door without this issue?

Comment: The fact you're using an `IHttpHandler` is irrelevant - all Azure Front Door sees is the actual response headers. So, have you conducted a request/response trace to confirm (_without any doubt_) that Azure Front Door is dropping headers?

Comment: Also, the error is about the `Content-Type` header - nothing to do with CORS....

Comment: Please share your entire Azure Front-Door configuration.

Comment: @Dai I agree the handler should be irrelevant, but somehow here we are. 

Do you have a recommended method for conducting the request/response trace? 

Correct, the issue is with the browser receiving files that did not have the Content-Type set.  By FD config, would an "Export template" aka Deployment template work?